# Send file to another app from a list of apps in xamarin & android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, f#, xamarin.android

I can't figure how send a file to shared in others apps, that I need to filter from a small list of it. I have read several tutorials and answers (like [Share file to another app (whatsapp, telegram, gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543089/share-file-to-another-app-whatsapp-telegram-gmail)) with no success:

```
override this.OnCreate (bundle) =

    base.OnCreate (bundle)
    this.SetContentView (Resources.Layout.Main)

    let button = this.FindViewById<Button>(Resources.Id.myButton)
    button.Click.Add (fun args -> 
        let fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        let fileName = Path.Combine([|fileName; "AboutAssets.txt"|]) |> Path.GetFullPath
        this.Launch(fileName)
    )

member this.Launch(fileName:string) =

    let context = Android.App.Application.Context
    let getUri file =
        Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", file)

    let file = new Java.IO.File(fileName)
    let path = getUri file
    let extension = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(path.ToString())
    let fileMime = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)

    let intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend)
    intent.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ClearTop) |>  ignore
    intent.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask) |>  ignore
    intent.SetType("*/*") |> ignore

    let apps = [| "excel"; "mail"; "gmail"; "whatsapp"; "dropbox"; "drive" |]

    let findApps() =
        let packageManager = context.PackageManager
        let resInfo = packageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.Activities)

        let targetedShareIntents = new ResizeArray<IParcelable>()

        let pkgs = seq {
            for info in resInfo do
                let namePkg = info.ActivityInfo.PackageName.ToLower()
                let nameApp = info.ActivityInfo.Name.ToLower()

                let label = info.LoadLabel(packageManager)
                let icon = info.Icon;


                for app in apps do
                    if nameApp.Contains(app) || namePkg.Contains(app) then
                        yield (app, info)
        }

        for (app, info) in pkgs |> Seq.distinct do
            let label = info.LoadLabel(packageManager)
            let icon = info.Icon;

            let targetedShare = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend)

            if app.Contains("email") then
                targetedShare.SetType("message/rfc822") |> ignore //not work
            else
                targetedShare.SetType(fileMime) |> ignore
            targetedShare.SetType(fileMime) |>  ignore

            targetedShare.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "My body of post/email") |>  ignore
            targetedShare.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission) |>  ignore

            targetedShare.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, path) |> ignore
            targetedShare.SetData(path)|>  ignore
            targetedShare.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ClearTop) |>  ignore
            targetedShare.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask) |>  ignore

            //targetedShare.SetData(uri) |> ignore
            let label = new Android.Content.PM.LabeledIntent(targetedShare, info.ActivityInfo.PackageName, label, icon)
            targetedShareIntents.Add(label) |>  ignore

        targetedShareIntents

    let apps = findApps()
    printf "%A" apps
```

Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, apps)

```
    let chooser = Android.Content.Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App")
    chooser.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, apps.ToArray()) |> ignore

    chooser.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ClearTop)|> ignore
    chooser.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask) |> ignore           

    context.StartActivity(chooser)
```

When I open gmail, the file not show, and not error is displayed. When open Google Drive it say "Upload was not sucessfull, request contained no data"

P.D: The config:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.basura.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

And provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: What does your FileProvider in your manifest look like?

Comment: Hard code the package name in the authorities and "assuming" your provider_paths is exporting the proper name/path.

Comment: I do the changes, as edited, with the same results.